# Communication between google drive API and jetpack compose app

Tags: java, kotlin, google-drive-api, android-jetpack-compose

Firstly, I don't know if it's important to specify it but I'm using Jetpack compose and I'm a beginner in Android development.

I'm building an app that should communicate with Google Drive in order to upload and download light datas. For that, I tried to add these dependencies in the build.gradle file of my app (as recommended in this [doc page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java)):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20220815-2.0.0'
}
```

Then I just copy-pasted [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads) Java sample code in my project and I used the "convert Java to Kotlin" feature of android studio to convert the sample to kotlin code. You can see the result of this conversion here:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.util.*

/* Class to demonstrate use-case of drive's download file. */
object DownloadFile {
    /**
     * Download a Document file in PDF format.
     *
     * @param realFileId file ID of any workspace document format file.
     * @return byte array stream if successful, `null` otherwise.
     * @throws IOException if service account credentials file not found.
     */
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun downloadFile(realFileId: String?): ByteArrayOutputStream {
        /* Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
           TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
          guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application.*/
        val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
            .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
        val requestInitializer: HttpRequestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(
            credentials
        )

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        val service = Drive.Builder(
            NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            requestInitializer
        )
            .setApplicationName("Drive samples")
            .build()
        return try {
            val outputStream: OutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            service.files()[realFileId]
                .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream)
            outputStream as ByteArrayOutputStream
        } catch (e: GoogleJsonResponseException) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            System.err.println("Unable to move file: " + e.details)
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Before being able to run this code I have 2 importation issues. I can't import HttpCredentialsAdapter and GoogleCredentials. It seems that com.google.auth can't be found to import `com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter` and `com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials`. What is the correct way to import these modules ?

Furethermore, I find the sample code a little weird. Why not just create a function downloadFile(Id) directly rather than wrap it in a class DownloadFile? Is that a Java pratice to wrap everything in class ?

Comment: "Is that a Java pratice to wrap everything in class ?" Yes, Java requires that everything be wrapped in a class.  Kotlin hides that implementation detail from you, although it still happens in the bytecode.

Comment: ok I see! Do you know what's wrong with the import ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm guessing here, but [this page](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter) suggests that at least `HttpCredentialsAdapter` is part of [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java), so try adding that dependency.